# Results of a PDO query not displaying

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

I'm trying to make a PDO query to display data. 
This is what i have done so far :

in my models/pdo, i created a class with this:

```
<?php

class VengeanceUsers {

    public static function getNumbersOfregistered()
    {
      $connexion = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost ;dbname=databasetest", 'root', 'passe'); // connexion à la BDD

      $var_dump($connexion);
      exit();
      $resultats=$connexion->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ope_tartine_nl "); // on va chercher tous les membres de la table qu'on trie par ordre croissant
      return $resultats;
    }

}

?>
```

**In my controller:**

```
$this->view->nb_users = VengeanceUsers::getNumbersOfregistered();
```

**In my view:**

```
Nombre d'inscrits : <?php echo $this->nb_users; ?><br/>
```

I don't have anything displayed...
Can anyone help me on this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You forgot to comment `exit();` out.
2. In `$var_dump($connexion);` you need to remove `$` in the beginning.
3. You need to fetch results from the statement.

For #3 you can use:

```
$sth = $connexion->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ope_tartine_nl "); // get statement
$resultats = $sth->fetchColumn(); // get data
return $resultats;
```

Comment: Actually i have an error 

Fatal error:  Class 'VengeanceUsers' not found in D:\\softs\\UwAmp\\www\\cdis-vengeance\\dev\\applications\\vengeance\\controllers\\AdminController.php on line 48

How can i fix this please ?
PS: thanks for your first advices

Comment: You forgot to include the file with your `VengeanceUsers` definition.

Comment: it tried to put this : include_once(VengeanceUsers.php);

At the top of my controller, just before "class AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action" but this is not working

Comment: Well, first of all, you specify the file name as a string, so it should be `include_once('VengeanceUsers.php');`. Second, you need to make sure that the path is correct. I doubt that class is in the same folder. You need some sort of `HOME` constant defined with path to your project dir, and then you specify `include_once(HOME . '/classes/VengeanceUsers.php');` with your correct path.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $resultats=$connexion->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ope_tartine_nl "); // on va chercher tous les membres de la table qu'on trie par ordre croissant
```

This only gives you the result object of the query.

You have to actually fetch the row from your result.

```
  $resultats=$connexion->query("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ope_tartine_nl "); // on va chercher tous les membres de la table qu'on trie par ordre croissant
  $numRows = $resultats->fetchColumn();
  return $numRows;
```

This should fix it

Comment: Actually i have an error Fatal error: Class 'VengeanceUsers' not found in D:\\softs\\UwAmp\\www\\cdis-vengeance\\dev\\applications\\vengeance\\controllers\\AdminCo‌​ntroller.php on line 48 How can i fix this please ? PS: thanks for your first advices

Comment: You haven't included the file where you defined the "class VengeanceUsers" . Include it and you should be fine

Comment: it tried to put this : include_once(VengeanceUsers.php); At the top of my controller, just before "class AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action" but this is not working

Comment: @Ranty has some great explainations so you should refer to his ;)